# Create a photo feed using a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create a photo feed using a UITableView. I have the code to create the table and, when a photo is taken, display it in the feed but the image isn't displaying. The image is defiantly being captured and if I use a UIImageView to display it, it works, but when I try to add it to the table, it doesn't. I have also noticed that when I click on a row of the empty table, my didSelectRow action isn't working so I'm not sure if the problem is with the table or the way the image is being displayed.

Here is the code I am using to create the table:

```
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
[_tableView release];
[self.tableView release];
```

Here is the rest of the code for the table:

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource
// number of section(s), now I assume there is only 1 section
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)theTableView
{
    return 1;
}

// number of row in the section, I assume there is only 1 row
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //    if (indexPath.section >= self.objects.count) {
    //        // Load More Section
    //        return 320.0f;
    //    }
    //
    return 320.0f;
}

// the cell will be returned to the tableView
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HistoryCell";
    // Similar to UITableViewCell, but
    PhotoCell *cell = (PhotoCell *)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PhotoCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    // Just want to test, so I hardcode the data
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = @"Testing";
    cell.thumbImage = self.thumbImage;
    //cell.backgroundView = self.thumbImage;

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate
// when user tap the row, what action you want to perform
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detailsViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Here is the PhotoCell.M:

```
 #import "PhotoCell.h"
#import "FeedViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation PhotoCell

@synthesize thumbImage = _thumbImage;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // configure control(s)

        UIImageView *testView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.thumbImage];
        testView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320);
        [self addSubview:testView];
        [self bringSubviewToFront:testView];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a quickie (I have no tested this is Xcode)

Try this:

```
#import "PhotoCell.h"
#import "FeedViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface PhotoCell ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImageView testView;
@end

@implementation PhotoCell

@synthesize thumbImage = _thumbImage;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // configure control(s)

        self.testView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.testView];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.testView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320);
}

- (void) setThumbImage:(UIImage *)image{
    _thumbImage = image;
    self.testView.image = _thumbImage
}
@end
```

Okay so:

I have removed the frame information from the `init` method because at the point the cell does not know its frame moving this into `layoutSubviews` is safer for the time where you want to add a more complex layout (even though all you have in this cell is a image)

I override the default setter for `self.thumbImage` so that instead of storing the UIImage object we also tell the imageView (testView) what the image is, and that should display it.

It is also good practise to add all subviews of a cell into `self.contentView` not `self` because apple does a lot of auto-magic stuff with its cell states and adding subviews to self could cause undesired behaviour in edit mode for instance.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Even with this implemented, the image is still not displaying after the photo is being taken. Does it change anything that at first, thumbImage was nothing attached, but after the user takes a photo it should update the table. Also the didSelecRow method is not working so maybe something is wrong with the table as a whole, not just the image that is being displayed

Comment: hrmm, okay so let me get the flow straight:
`displaytable->take photo-> refresh table`

are you refreshing the table using `[tableview reloadData]`?
and are you adding the photo into the table's data array properly?

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you, I was missing the [tableview reloadData]! This is working great and displaying the image, but when the image is displayed it is squeezed down, where as I would like it to crop the image. I am currently using UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill to crop it, is there a better way?

Comment: Look at [UIViewContentMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewContentMode), I think the one you want is `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`

Comment: This may by a very advanced question, but when the user takes another photo, it will then create another cell above the previous one and save both. If you say, closed the app and reopend the app, the images would still be there. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Yeah, that is a little advanced and out of the scope of this question but you will need to look into persisting these images inside your applications sandbox; CoreData or saving these images to the Documents directory.

Comment: Thats what I thought, Thanks for all your help throughout this

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because at the time of 'initWithStyle' in PhotoCell.M the thumbImage property is not set yet.

If it was me I would override the setThumbImage function of PhotoCell to set the image to the imageview.

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

When testView is alloc,the self.thumbImage is nil at that time.

you can simply set cell.imageView.image to have a try!